# Get the default value of http.sslCAInfo in Git

Tags: linux, git, ssl

I have a Git repository with two remotes, which I access over `https`. One of the remote server has a "normal" `ssl` certificate (issued by a recognised CA), the other a self-signed certificate.

If I do not set `http.sslCAInfo`, I can access the first server but not the second (the self-signed certificate not being found by Git). If I set `http.sslCAInfo` to point to the self-signed certificate, the second server can be accessed but not the first (this time because Git cannot find the certificates which - I assume - are provided by my OS).

Thus, I want to know how I can get the default value of Git variable `http.sslCAInfo`, so I can specify it and append the path to my self-signed certificate. Any other method to solve the original problem is of course welcome.